# Importing Mainframe RMF3 logs into Hadoop environment

Tags: logging, hadoop, mainframe

I want to import mainframe RMF3 logs(.bin format) to hadoop. I am not sure of the process to be followed, could someone explain me on how to go about importing these files into hadoop and do the data structuring activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMF Mon III is not normally described as "logs" but I'm assuming you're meaning the SMF records that Mon III can be induced to cut. Or do you mean the VSAM data sets it uses?

In any case there probably isn't a commercially-available mapping of the records that's useful to hadoop. What formats will it take? I'm assuming at least CSV and JSON.

Your challenge will be to "flatten" SMF records and map them. Or else to extract records from the VSAM data sets and map them.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: I am completely new to the mainframe side and trying to understand how RMF captures data.

Comment: Can you please share a brief info on SMF and VSAM records to help me understand the topic. I have having a rmf outputed .bin file with me and not sure of the contents of it

Answer (score 1):

This an expansion on @Martin Packer answer and I am not an expert on SMF / RMF.

The short answer:  Look for an **existing tool** at your site to convert RMF log records to something you would be more comfortable with, e.g. is [RMF Tools](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/rmf/tools/rmftools.html#pmos390) available ???

---

**SMF** is a data format used by IBM of logging system actions on the mainframe. It is a binary format.

- Chapter 13 in [SMF Data](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/IEA2G292/CCONTENTS?SHELF=IEA2BK91&DN=SA22-7630-19&DT=20090114021602) lists the various record types.

  - For example the header section of a Job start record is [Job start header](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/IEA2G292/13.25.2.1?SHELF=IEA2BK91&DT=20090114021602&CASE=).
- There are tools for converting it to other formats see [RMF Tools](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/rmf/tools/rmftools.html#pmos390), You may already have a license for this ???

**VSAM** is a file format that allows access to records via there key's (i.e. it a [ISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM) format like Berkley DB or C-ISAM). A lot of Mainframe packages (presumable RMF3) use VSAM to store data.

- The initial version of a lot of mainframe packages was in 70's when there was no SQL DB like DB2. VSAM was available on all ZOS (MVS etc in those days) while there was no common-DB available.

---

**Update 28 June 2014:**

There is a project https://github.com/tmalaska/CopybookInputFormat that should be ale to process SMS data.

The project uses [JRecord](http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/)to read data via a copybook. **JRecord** does support Mainframe Binary file formats directly.

While [JRecord](http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/) is normally used with Cobol-Copyboooks, **JRecord** also supports Xml and Csv copybooks (or you could write your own copybook reader).
JRecord does support the Mainframe Binary file formats.

Comment: Thanks Bruce.. The info was very helpful.. I have with me SMF data and plan to import it into Hadoop environment and need to figure out the data structure.  I see the data generated every 100seconds from mainframes. Do the SMF records follow fixed data structure everytime?

Comment: There are many record-types + extension records. But each record-type will be fixed format. They may also have an optional section at the end. Unfortunately it is 25 years since I worked directly with SMF data.